# What are the advantages of lock-free programming over spin lock？

Tags: multithreading, lock-free, spinlock, lockless

I am wondering which are the advantages of lock-free programming over spin lock？ I think that when we do lock free programming using CAS mechanism in a thread(called A), if other thread change the value in CAS, A thread still need to loop again. And I think it just like we use spin lock!

I am so confused about this. Although I know that CAS and spin-lock are suitable to use when the lock contention is not fierce, can someone explain in which scenarios lock free should be used and spin lock should be used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lock-freedom provides what is called *progress guarantee*. You are right that in your example thread `A` has do perform a retry (i.e., loop again), but *only if some other thread changed the value*, which implies that that thread was able to make progress.

In contrast, a thread (let's call it `X`) that holds a spin-lock prevents all other threads from making progress until the lock is released. So if thread `X` is preempted, execution of all threads waiting for the lock is effectively stalled until `X` can resume execution and finally release the lock. If `X` were to be stalled indefinitely, then all other threads would also be blocked indefinitely.

Such a situation is not possible with lock-free algorithms, since it is guaranteed that at any time at least one thread can make progress.

---

Which should be used depends on the situation. Lock-free algorithms are inherently difficult to design, especially for more complex data structures like trees. And even if you have a lock-free algorithm, it is almost always slower than a serial one, so a serial version protected by a lock might perform better. Then again, if the data structure is heavily contended, a lock-free version will scale better than one protected by a lock. However, if your workload is mostly read-only, a read-write-lock will also provide good scalability. Unfortunately, there is no general rule here...

---

If you want to learn more about lock-freedom (and more) I recommend the book [The Art of Multiprocessor Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123973376).
If you prefer free alternatives I recommend [Is Parallel Programming Hard, And, If So, What Can You Do About It?](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.00854) by Paul McKenney or [Practicallock-freedom](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/techreports/UCAM-CL-TR-579.pdf) by Keir Fraser.